# Diamond operator on a meromorphic function

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Is there a standard way in which the diamond operator for modular forms is defined for an arbitrary meromorphic function?. I know the definition for a weight k modular form, but since I usually wont have a weight, then whats the correct way to define the diamond operator now?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No; the diamond operators are truly modular objects.